# Where is the best place to create a child control of a child window in a pure WinAPI GUI App?

Tags: c++, winapi, window, parent-child

I am working on a WinAPI only application. I want to create a STATIC child window that will be used as a "container" to child controls. In the examples that I have found so far, the "container" window is created catching the WM_CREATE in the main window procedure. I assumed the best place to create the child controls of the child window was by catching the WM_CREATE for the child window. To do this, I first need to subclass the child window to point to the new window procedure. The thing is the window is created before it is subclassed, therefore the WM_CREATE is sent to the original procedure rather than to my user created procedure. I can of course create the child controls after creating the child static window inside the main window procedure, but I do not believe this to be the best way to do it. What is the best option?

Working sample code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWND hContainer = CreateWindow(WC_STATIC, L"Container", WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 100, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_CONTAINER, NULL, NULL);
        WNDPROC wpOldProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hContainer, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)ChildWindowProc);
        HWND hButton = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, L"Button", WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 20, 10, hContainer, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL); // This works well
    }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK ChildWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
       // HWND hButton = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, L"Button", WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 20, 10, hContainer, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL); 
       // This point is never reached because the WM_CREATE message is sent before subclassing of the window
    }
    break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return CallWindowProc(gsHdl.wpTE, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Why bother (mis)using a static control when you can just create your own window class?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Jonathan!

Comment: Make sure to read [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/subclassing-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main principal here is separation of concerns: A window will typically create its children in response to its WM_CREATE message as:

This ensures the window "owns" the creation of its children. It also guarantees that when the parent window is created directly by classname, all the children get automatically created. And lastly, because WM_CREATE is sent before a window is made visible/painted, it ensures that the child windows are all created by the time the window is first painted.

A lot of these considerations fall away when using child windows to organise child windows :- If you are making a proper abstracted control window that is one thing, but if you are just arranging some relatively standard windows controls that you want the main window to be able to interact with then deep hierarchies are annoying to navigate, there are some weirdness in how mouse and painting happen where you might want to actually arrange the container and its children in the "wrong" z-order that you could not achieve if they were strictly arranged as child/parents.

Which is to say there is nothing wrong with creating a static window, and using the returned HWND as a parent window on subsequent lines - especially if that reduces the number of window classes, lines of code / creation convolution - and simplifies the parent windows relationship to its controls.

Answer (score 0):

Creating sub-windows/controls under `WM_CREATE` messages does ensure that sub-windows/controls are created after successful window creation and that all sub-windows/sub-controls are automatically created when creating the main window.

But I don't think it's much different from the below：

```
HWND hContainer = CreateWindow (WC_STATIC, L "Container", WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 100, 50, hWnd, (HMENU) ID_CONTAINER, NULL, NULL);
if(hContainer)
{
    HWND hButton = CreateWindow (WC_BUTTON, L "Button", WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 0, 0, 20, 10, hContainer, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL);
}
```

It also ensures the creation order and preconditions.

If you really need to modify `WinProc` and capture `WM_CREATE` messages in a standard windows controls, `SetWindowsLongPtr` does not meet your requirements. Use [`SetClassLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclasslongptra#GCLP_WNDPROC) before creating "Container" instead.

Comment: This breaks keyboard navigation, unless you set the [WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles) style on the child controls' parents.